# How to backup my Windows Mobile 6 device from PC?

Tags: windows-7, backup, 64-bit, windows-mobile, activesync

It was an option in ActiveSync previously which is now gone -- to backup all device content into file on connected PC. Please, recommend software, which can do this with WM6 and Windows Mobile Device Center and Windows 7 x64.

I need not a software which works on WM6 itself.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like PIM will do what you're looking for:

"The free PIM Backup utility makes backup copies of your appointments, call logs, contacts, messages, speed dials, tasks, and even folders and file types you specify. PIM Backup jobs run manually or on a schedule you set"

http://lifehacker.com/397750/pim-backup-backs-up-windows-mobile-data